# jQuery inArray always finds matches when there isnt any

Tags: jquery

I am using inArray to determine if a value is in an array like so:

```
$.each($("input[type=checkbox]#type"), function (x, y) {

        if ($.inArray(o, $(y).val().toString())) {
            console.log("Here");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not Here");
        }

    });
```

the values inside o are:

```
var o = [11, 17, 5];
```

and here are my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="10" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="11" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="17" />
<input type="checkbox" id="type" value="20" />
```

But according to my console logs "Here" appears for each one, why is it doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `$.inArray` doesn't return value `-1` which means not found . Also, you need to convert that value of checkbox as `integer` using `parseInt` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var o = [11, 17, 5];
$.each($("input[type=checkbox]"), function(x, y) {
  var value = parseInt($(y).val()) //parse as integer
  //check if return value is not -1( means found)
  if ($.inArray(value, o) !== -1) {
    console.log("Here ---" + value);
  } else {
    console.log("Not Here");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input type="checkbox" value="11" />
<input type="checkbox" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" value="17" />
<input type="checkbox" value="20" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the parameters of `$.inArray()` method swapped around.

> [jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ]
> )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)
>
> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).
>
> > **value**: The value to search for.
> >
> > **array**: An array through which to search.
> >
> > **fromIndex** (optional): The index of the array at which to begin the search. The default is 0, which will search the whole array.

Every ID in a given document should be unique, but more than one element can have the same `name` attribute. Also, as stated by @swati, you need to convert the value to an `integer` since the elements of the array are `integers`.

**DEMO**

```js
var o = [11, 17, 5];
$.each($("input[type=checkbox][name=type]"), function(x, y) {
  var value = +y.value; //or parseInt(y.value)
  if ($.inArray(value, o) > -1) {
    console.log("Here ---" + value);
  } else {
    console.log("Not Here");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="10" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="11" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="17" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="20" />
```

You could use the [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method instead of `$.inArray()` method, which returns a `boolean`,  as follows:

**DEMO**

```js
var o = [11, 17, 5];
$.each($("input[type=checkbox][name=type]"), function(x, y) {
  var value = +y.value; //or parseInt(y.value)
  if (o.includes(value)) { //array.includes(value)
    console.log("Here ---" + value);
  } else {
    console.log("Not Here");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="10" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="11" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="17" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="20" />
```